# error Option "--entry-file" is missing. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I tried to install native react and when I enter the command npm run android-windows there;s error.

How to solve this?

This is my packages.json

{
  "name": "Fyp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android-windows": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false npm run android-windows--entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.3.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

This is the error

error Option "--entry-file" is missing. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Option "--entry-file" is missing
    at C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\assertRequiredOptions.js:51:13
    at Array.forEach ()
    at assertRequiredOptions (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\assertRequiredOptions.js:40:11)
    at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:159:42)
    at Command.listener (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
    at Command.parse (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)
    at setupAndRun (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:210:24)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\user\Fyp\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:173:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Fyp@0.0.1 android-windows: `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false npm run android-windows--entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/ass
ets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Fyp@0.0.1 android-windows script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-06T15_03_19_543Z-debug.log

Answer (score 3):

try this commands:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

reference link : [how to build apk file](https://medium.com/@raguct25/how-to-generate-apk-file-from-react-native-f4fbc923bfdb)

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android  --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res
```

the link [here](https://medium.com/codingtown/how-to-generate-apk-file-from-react-native-f4fbc923bfdb) need fixations